# Python grabbing data from an outlook folder

Tags: python, outlook

I am currently trying to figure out how to grab attachments from emails in a specific folder. Every Thursday, an email will arrive in my weekly reports folder and I would like to have a script that will grab the attachments of the email and save it to a specific file location.

This is the code I have so far which I believe is correct to instantiate everything.

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case the inbox. You can change that number to reference
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
```

However, I am unsure of how to procede as I have been unable to find good documentation of this module. What would be the next steps in order to grab from a specific folder, in this case it is one below the inbox folder, and save the first email's attachments to a specific location?

If it makes any difference, there are 4 csv files in the weekly email

Thanks

Comment: I've never had good luck with win32com and getting office and python to play nice (except for openpyxl which works really well). Use VBA?

Comment: @PatrickConwell Can you direct me to a good source to be able to do what I need in VBA?

Comment: Nothing in particular - I'd just google. I don't know that much about VBA other than keep searching for what you need until you find it. Just FYI, there are a bunch of different version of office/VBA so be specific in your searches.